GitHub Workflow Deployment to Windows IIS Server
I need help with a GitHub workflow .yml file. I am trying to setup automated deployments from my repository to a website hosted in IIS on a Windows Server virtual machine that is also hosted in Azure. The repository contains a .NET Core 7 API which builds fine, the remainder of the yml executes fine as well but no files are copied to the website directory on the server.
I have also spent the past 3 days trying and debugging other yml solutions but every one either caused an error or didn't work for some other reason.
Could someone help me with this or provide a yml example to accomplish what I am trying to do?
name: Deploy to IIS

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout code
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Setup .NET
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.0 # Replace with your version

      # Build and publish
      - name: Build and Publish
        working-directory: OmegaBloods
        run: |
          dotnet publish -c Release -o published

      # Deploy to IIS
      - name: Deploy to IIS
        env:
          DEPLOY_IP: ${{ secrets.IIS_SERVER_IP }}
          DEPLOY_USER: ${{ secrets.IIS_USERNAME }}
          DEPLOY_PASS: ${{ secrets.IIS_PASSWORD }}
        working-directory: OmegaBloods
        run: |
          Write-Output "Get Location before Set-Location:" 
          Get-Location
          
          Set-Location 'D:\a\OmegaBloods\OmegaBloods\OmegaBloods\published'
          
          Write-Output "Get Location:" 
          Get-Location
          
          Write-Output "Begin Deployment"
          
          Test-WSMan -ComputerName $env:DEPLOY_IP
          Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $env:DEPLOY_IP -Force
          
          Compress-Archive -Path .\* -DestinationPath app.zip
          
          $DestinationPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UserCentralAPI"
          $SourcePath = Get-Location

          $password = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:DEPLOY_PASS -AsPlainText -Force
          $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($env:DEPLOY_USER, $password)

          Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:DEPLOY_IP -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
              param($DestinationPath)
              Write-Output "Get Destination: $DestinationPath"
          
              Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path $DestinationPath
              New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $DestinationPath
              
              Write-Output "Get Directory Contents:"
              Get-ChildItem
          } -ArgumentList $DestinationPath

          Write-Output "Get Location:" 
          Get-Location
          
          Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath -Destination $DestinationPath -Recurse
          Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:DEPLOY_IP -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { iisreset }

